# Form inserts empty field in Database even though the field is made compulsory

Tags: database, forms, validation, email, form-submit

I have a simple form with a few compulsory fields such as Name and Email. Email has the standard validation checking that comes with form.

But somehow, a user entered something in the email field that got stored as an empty value in the database email field for that record.

I am unable to replicate the scenario. Whatever I try, the validation message pops up saying that I need to enter an "@" and something after @.

What value when entered into email field will get accepted and get stored as empty value in database?

Comment: I can only guess you are refering to web form... So you should add some more details... What kind of validation took place, was there validations at the server side? What db (add this to the tags) and so on... Many errors could have caused this.

Comment: Yes, it is a web form. Values get stored to PHP myadmin DB. Validation takes place at server side. Standard webform validation for email. an @ is required and some text after @ is required.

Comment: @It-Z - could you tell me any possible scenario where this could happen?

Comment: Assuming the form verification is correct, let's say some one facked a post message with incorrect mail format... We now need to deal with the server side verification - is it working properly? You said the field is mandatory - by what method is this verified? Are null values are acceptable? These are just a few things to check. Without some of the code, html and scripts it is just a guessing game :(

Comment: The verification is working properly as far as I tested. If I try to submit by leaving the field blank, it says an "@" is required. When I just type @, it says something after @ is also required. So I'm unable to submit it with an empty value. I want to know if there is any other syntax that gets stored as null when entered.

Comment: If, by malicious act, some one, with out using your form, directly submit malformed data, in order to bypass the front end verification (which is tested and working as you and me are assuming) - what the server is doing with this bad data? Will it check it? Store it? The submit process is made from many steps, each needs to be tested. If you could show us some of the relevant, front and back ends, code we will be able to assist you further.